# How can vbscript get javascript postback webform data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript, dopostback

Firstly, I am new to all kinds of scripting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using Vbscript to try and grab data submitted via javascript:webform postback, and I am lost. I know absolutely nothing about javascript.

Every time someone adds something to the input field & clicks the Add button, a form(?) is created on the page adding this info, for example the number "123456789", click Add, "987654321", click add...a list is created.

After I click add, those variables still do not show up in the source coding, so I do not know how to get that infomation.

Here is the Javascript postback info :

```
'<input type="button" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button2" value="Add" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;icn&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button2" tabindex="6" style="font-size: xx-small" />'
```

Here is the input field the info gets entered into :

```
'<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CCICN" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CCICN" tabindex="4" style="width:104px;text-align: center" />'
```

There are several hidden input fields.. and a viewstate one with a insanely long value.

```
'<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />'
```

I am unsure what other information you would need to help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by looping through the tables, then looping through the table cells.

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
Set table_html = objie.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
n = 1   
For Each table in table_html
x = table.innertext
If instr(x,"keywordsearchingfor") Then
    results = msgbox (n & ". " & vbnewline & x,vbOKCancel)
    if results = "2" Then
       wscript.quit
    end if
end if
n = n + 1    
Next
```

N will give you the table #.
Then once I narrowed down what table it was in, found what cell it was in by using this :

```
Set table_html = objie.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(20).getelementsbytagname("td")
```

Then N will give you the cell #.